# dependency errors from wine preventing installations of all programs

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am unable to down load any application from Ubuntu software center.
while down loading I get a window with this message.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package
```

Comment: Can you summarize your problem by editing your post with an actual question?

Comment: Have you changed the error message? Because it seems the version required is already installed

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to resolve this conflict by asking apt to do it for you.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use synaptic package manager and check the problems.
[image]

Comment: Synaptic is installed by default and the dependency errors reported may prevent installing other software, including Synaptic... Then you say "check the problems"... Where? How? C'mon, a little more effort in answering goes a long way.